# Trying to restore cloned 1TB HDD to 3TD HDD, no other solutions have worked

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, gpt

So one day my 1TB started to fail, losing many sectors every boot. So I cloned the 1TB hard drive to a 1TB external drive. First problem? The target drive is too small. Fixed that by telling it to ignore the size check, since the target disk was only 1 sector smaller. I had ~100GB of empty space, so one sector wouldn't make me loose anything. So that worked fine, so then I bought a standard 3TB drive, installed it and it works.

But here's where the problems start: I try to clone the old data to the new hard drive. It's too big, switch it to GPT. So I booted up Ubuntu Live, used Gparted and created a new GPT partition table, and I've tried both creating no partitions and creating NTFS partitions. When I try to restore it to either a 1.5TB partition, or the whole thing, I get "ntfsclone-ng.c: NTFS volume 'dev/sda1' is scheduled for a check or it was shutdown uncleanly. Please boot windows or fix it by fsck."

So I tried fsck, that didn't do anything. Then I tried to install windows, but I couldn't install onto a GPT table, despite it also being NTFS. So in the install I deleted those patitions and let windows install, but it only created a 2TB partition and left the last TB unallocated. Ran a chkdsk, that said nothing was wrong. Tried to restore cloned disk, can't use MBR on drives over 2.2TB. So I created a 1.5TB partition and restored it on that. Same ntfsclone error.

But it has to be GPT, so then I tried to install windows 7 64 bit through the UEFI: option on the USB. Note that the regular, non-UEFI windows installed and ran just fine, but when I tried to install it on UEFI it gave me a windows failed to start to start, error code 0xc0000007, \windows\system32\boot\winload.efi is missing or corrupted. So I looked at the USB and in the install.wim in the sources file, the winload.efi is in the folder 2, but not in the folder 1. I'm assuming that the UEFI install is in folder 2. So that's not it. And I already did all those steps in diskpart about formatting as FAT32 and marking as active and assigning, and I moved the boot folder from the windows folder up one so it read EFI\BOOT\ and I got the bootmgrw file (but I couldn't find it locally, oddly, so I just downloaded it from a guide) and renamed it bootx64.efi and put it in the boot folder, so I did everything all the guides said on how to create UEFI windows 7 USB install. I even tried roofus a few times.

So I enabled that block thing in Clonezilla where it works with all file types but is really slow. Did it with windows already installed, didn't work. Did it was a blank drive, it worked... but it was only a TB large and I couldn't expand it.

In summation, the current problem is I can't boot in UEFI windows 7 install, which is what I need so I can make it GPT, have the disks not need checking, and be able to restore the cloned data.

Comment: It's hard to follow all this, but I would simply clone the 1TB drive to the 3TB without resizing (leaving 2TB unused).  This allows you to continue using MBR.  Once your Windows is starting happily, you can worry about converting to GPT or expanding the partition.

Comment: The problem is that converting to GPT deletes all the data, and I'm pretty sure the window's that's installed on the old hard drive wasn't installed in UEFI mode, so converting it to GPT would just break it.

Comment: There [are ways to do it](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gptgen/) without losing data.

Comment: So I made a 1TB partition in MBR, and attempted to restore the old data to the new partition, and just got that "please boot windows or fix it by fsck" error again.

Comment: don't create the partition.  clone the disk (without resizing), not the partition.

Comment: Cloning the disk leads to the maximum 2TB limit.

Comment: Why would there be a 2TB limit cloning a 1TB disk without resizing?

Comment: It's only cloning 1TB of data, but I think because of how cloning works, when using disk to disk it attempts to use MBR on the whole 3TB, which returns an error.

Comment: MBR's limit of 2TB applies to partitions, not disks

Comment: Is there a parameter or option that's not default for cloning the disk without resizing on clonezilla? The -k bypassed the 3TB limit but still gave that "boot windows or fix it by fsck" error.

Comment: Unchecked the `-r` each time and then tried all the partition options, always led to the same "fix it by fsck" error.